# Cakephp: How can make excerpt safer

Tags: php, cakephp

I use *$this->Text->excerpt()* in TextHelper for excerpt my post description. But, I realize that isn't safe. It maybe break up my web layout,

ex

```
<p>Advanced SystemCare 7 PRO provides automated and all-in-one PC care service with Malware Removal</p>
<p>It also creates...
```

It maybe excerpt without `</p>` tag and break up my layout

So, if you have any solution, please help me. Thanks

Comment: That method does not support HTML content (others do, like http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html#String::highlight ) - feel free to add the functionality and make a PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around it was to strip the tags beforehand.

```
$searchDisplayText = strip_tags($modelItemDetails[$model->alias][$fieldName]);

$searchDisplayTextTruncated = String::excerpt($searchDisplayText, $options['keyword'], $settings['excerptLength'] , '...');
```

You would need to do this anyway, as you probably don't want images or other unsafe items in your results, you only want text.